# SQL server 2008 Analysis Services DSO properties

Tags: ssas

We are planning to do Sharepoint and project server 2007 databases migration.

The share point website also processes cubes.

So we will be moving SSAS cubes from SQL 2005 to 2008 and then re-pointing the location from the sharepoint admin website.

The following document covers “Requirements for using SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services with the Project Server 2007 Cube Building Service”

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285466%28office.12%29.aspx

the document is easy to follow but there is a section which mentions:

“You need to configure the Analysis Services DSO properties so that the repository database is configured to be used from DSO in SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services. Changes made during this process will be reflected in the Analysis Services configuration file (Msmdsrv.ini).” So this involves playing with DSO* properties under the SSAS server.

[image]

The existing SSAS server has only sharepoint cubes but the new SSAS server has cubes for other applications too.

I can do the settings following this document but I want to know if there are any risks involved in changing DSO properties on SSAS server.

Can anyone please help or put me in right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by An Expert friend:

It wont effect other cubes. DSO component will only be used when a user runs DSO 8.0 application and will have no impact on SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services database.